# Speed when joining datasets in dplyr on moderately sized datasets

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm joining two datasets by a common identifier. Dataset A is 18022 rows*75 columns, while dataset B is 2.8mill rows*25 columns. I run

`left_join(A,B,by='identifier')`

However, the first two times it crashed and restarted Rstudio Server automatically without any warnings and now the third time it has run for 25 min. There is no progress bar. Any idea how long this process should take?

I am running on an EC2 instance (t2.micro) using the Rstudio server on the newest dplyr version.

Could the crash / performance be due to insufficient RAM allocated to the instance ?

Comment: You could be running into memory limits, depending on the details of `A` and `B` and your system specs. For example, let's say there are 1000 different unique values of `identifier` in `A` and that every row of `B` matches an `identifier` in `A`. Then the merged object could have up to about 50 million rows and a size of ~40GB (where the size estimate is based on a little experimentation with fake data on my computer). You can check how many rows your real merged object would have with `sum(table(A$identifier) * table(B$identifier[B$identifier %in% unique(A$identifier)]))`.

Comment: I left the computer running all night, but it was still unresponsive this morning and I had to terminate the instance in order to abort the process. Running your nifty computation reveals that it should end up with 2818929 rows - which should be manageable for the instance.

Comment: It was due to insufficient RAM. After increasing the RAM on my EC2 instance it worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to solve your problem.